# How to fetch record from another table if first table return no record using UNION in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have two table name 'activites' & 'archived_activities'. I devide my activities table record into another table record. Activities table contain  only first 200 latest activities of users and remaining record moved to archived_activities table. Now I want to join both table only when activities table return null then I want to use same offset and limit for archived_activities table to fetch next record. Below I my query that is not working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id=87 LIMIT 180,20
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id=87 LIMIT 180,20
```

But this query working not fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

One approach here would be to do a union to get both current and archived records into one logical table, but to order them such that current records get higher priority, should they exist.  I assign a position of 1 to current records and 2 to archived records.  Then, I order by this position and retain 200 records.

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2, ..., 1 AS position
    FROM activities
    WHERE user_id = 87
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2, ..., 2
    FROM archived_activities
    WHERE user_id = 87
) t
ORDER BY
    position
LIMIT 200;
```

Comment: Seems like a better solution than mine @RizwanSaleem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM activities
WHERE user_id=87
LIMIT 180,20
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM archieve_activities 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM activities 
                 WHERE user_id = 87)
  AND user_id=87
LIMIT 180,20
```

Comment: But what happens if the first table has say 100 records, and 100 should therefore be fetched from the archive table?

Comment: "only when activities table return null then I.." It sounds like it's not the case .. Let's wait for OP to comment @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
select * from activities as a 
union all
select * from archived_activities as b 
where b.user_id not in 
(select r.user_id
 from activities as r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the `UNION` Answers does the `LIMIT 180, 20` optimally for the general case.

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 200 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 200 )
ORDER BY .. LIMIT 180, 20
```

This will get the 'right' 20 rows regardless of whether either `SELECT` finds less than, or more than, 200 rows.

(Note, the '200' comes from '180+20'.)